# How to change search query in quick search from 'like%' => '%like%'

Tags: magento2, catalogsearch, search-criteria

I have word to search 'luma'
I type 'lum'in search then I have result. But i type 'uma', I have no result. I think query of search is "LIKE 'value%'". So i want change it to "LIKE '%value%'".
How can i do it. Thanks